# While running on android 4.0 , getting the http connection response code as 400 instead of 200 in live audio streaming project

Tags: android

I am working on an live audio streaming project, in which the live audio is playing well while running on devices upto android 3.0. It is getting the response code as 200. However, when running on android 4.0 emulator, it is stuck in my splash screen with getting the http connection response code as 400 instead of 200. Here is my UA:

```
httpCon.setRequestProperty( "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 1.0; en-us; dream) AppleWebKit/525.10+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0.4 Mobile Safari/523.12.2") .
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> http 400: Bad request

suggestion remove **setRequestProperty**, and try.